# jQuery Validate setDefaults not working after upgrade

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have recently upgraded my jQuery from 2.1.3 to 2.1.4 and jQueryValidation from 1.13.0 to 1.14.0 after that my jQueryValidation defaults stopped working. Not giving any error on console.

Here's debug findings:

```
// http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/
setDefaults: function( settings ) {
    $.extend( $.validator.defaults, settings );
}
```

At this point before extending **$.validator.defaults** value is:

[image: $.validator.defaults]

and after **$.extend**, **$.validator.defaults** value is :

[image: $.validator.defaults with my settings]

This means that defaults settings are updated according to my given settings. But end result is not what is expected. Here's the generated code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Experience <small>(in years) </small></label>
       <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmployeeSkillExperience" type="text" maxlength="4" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeSkillExperience" class="form-control error" required="required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
            <label id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeSkillExperience-error" class="error" for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeSkillExperience">This field is required.</label>
       </div>
</div>
```

It should have been like this:

```html
<div class="form-group has-error">
   <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Experience <small>(in years) </small></label>
   <div class="col-sm-7">
          <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmployeeSkillExperience" type="text" maxlength="4" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeSkillExperience" class="form-control" required="required" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeSkillExperience-error" aria-invalid="true">
         <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeSkillExperience-error" class="help-block">This field is required.</span>
     </div>
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question here.

Comment: @Adriaan since upgradation of couple of libraries defaults of jQueryValidation are not being setting according to above mentioned code. It also doesn't give any error. So I am wondering how to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Your results cannot be reproduced.  Your code original code is working:  http://jsfiddle.net/9yuaqL15/

Comment: Please do not edit the OP to remove the original content entirely and render all comments and answers meaningless.  Please just edit it to correct problems or add more information.

Answer (score 0):

> I have recently upgraded my jQuery from 2.1.3 to 2.1.4 and jQueryValidation from 1.13.0 to 1.14.0 after that my jQueryValidation defaults stopped working.

As per [the jQuery Validate website](http://jqueryvalidation.org), this plugin has **not** been tested with jQuery 2:

> **Dependencies**: 
>    jQuery, tested with 1.7.2, 1.8.3, 1.9.1, 1.11.1

<s>I suggest that you contact the developer on [his GitHub page](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) and make a request.</s>  In the meantime, use a jQuery Library version that you already know will work.

---

**EDIT**:

The `.setDefaults()` method **IS** working with jQuery 2.1.4 and jQuery Validate 1.14

**See:  http://jsfiddle.net/9yuaqL15/**

Comment: I have updated question and added my debug findings in it.

Comment: @user2290194, my findings are pretty clear.   The code you originally posted is working for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/9yuaqL15/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"</script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: add these scripts in your html. I had the same problem where my jQuery.validator.setDefaults() was not being executed by the browser. Found out that this was due to an old jquery reference and the new versions worked for me. Try it out.